# Customize error called Web API with incorrect parameters

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to customize the error that returns me when I make a call to the Web APIs but with size or type of the parameter is incorrect.

With this call:

```
http://xxxxx:xxxx/webapi/WebApi?id=2&type=**asdasds**
```

the application return me this error:

> The request is invalid. The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'type' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for
>   method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetValue(Int32, Int32)' in
>   'myapplication.WebApiController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.

The function that i call:

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal type As Integer) As IHttpActionResult
    /////////do something
End Function
```

The execution does not pass in the called function.
How can I customize the error is returned???

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Use `Try/Catch` block to return a proper error message

Comment: @iman no, that won't work, as the error is thrown by MVC before any user code runs.

Comment: Then use [ActionFilters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977224/asp-net-mvc-error-handling-using-action-filters-attributes) to catch exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Could you give an example related to my case?